# How can we install java through packaging

Tags: java

I have a java project in eclipse. I created exe file of my project using launch4j application. But I want that when exe file executed, it should check whether java is installed in an OS and if it is not installed then it should automatically install java or atleast should throw an error saying please install Java.

How can this be done? Do anyone have idea regarding this?

Comment: Try calling subprocess `java -h`.  If this works you can assume java is installed. Else java is not installed/not in path

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamically bundle a  JRE with install4j. Look for this feature "JRE Bundling and On-Demand Download of JREs" mentioned here.

https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/features.html

The documentation also covers how to do this.

http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/